# MP3 in Audio Tag in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, audio, mp3

I have this code that I'm using to play an MP3:

```
<p>Current Recording<br><br>
<audio controls='controls'><source src='".$rec_url."' type='audio/mp3' />
<a href='".$rec_url."'>Click to Download the Current Recording</a>
</audio></p>
```

I can see the Audio player in Chrome, and I can download the link in IE8. My problem is I just see a black box with an X in it on Firefox. I don't need to play it in this player in Firefox, I am aware that Firefox doesn't support the playing of MP3s.

But how do I get the link to show up?

Thanks!

UPDATE: This is what I see

[image]

Comment: Is a JavaScript solution acceptable?  Check the `error.code` property of the `audio` element, if it's `4` then replace the element with a link.  Note that in Firefox you can still right click and download the audio anyway.

Comment: This is great thank you robert, I'll try to see if I can utilize the error.code property. Regarding your second point, I was hoping that this would be the case, but it's actually grayed out. The option is Save Audio File As... or something similar and its inaccessible, I can put a screenshot if this is unusual behavior. I'll let you know if I can get the error.code of the audio tag. You should make this an answer :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the error.code property of the element and then removed the entire tag and replaced it with a link if it had a value of 4.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox does only support ogg and wave. You can do this:

```
<audio controls='controls'>
    <source src='".$rec_url."' type='audio/mp3' />
    <source src='".$rec_ogg_url."' type='audio/ogg' />
    <a href='".$rec_url."'>Click to Download the Current Recording</a>
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks topek, so there's no way to make the link show if its in Firefox? I don't have access to an ogg version of this mp3

Comment: Google may help: http://www.google.com/search?q=mp3+to+ogg

There many free tools that can help you to convert the file. The link does not show up due to the fact, that FF supports the audio tag and the link content inside the audio tag will only be displayed, when the browser does not support the tag.

Comment: I'm going to use robertc's suggestion, instead of duplicating the entire collection of mp3s, talk about a waste of time and space