# Playing Sounds On Javascript Events

Tags: javascript, audio

Is there a way that I could play a sound on an event in JavaScript with JavaScript or jQuery? It would be best if it was simple. Here's an example:

```
function play_song() {
    i = 0;
    b = 1;
    if (b > i) {
        play_sound(beep.mp3);
    }
}
```

Also, if it's a library, I'm looking for something that would actually work into JS functions, not any HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this way:

```
<div id="sound_element">
    <embed src=sound_file_url hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>   
</div>
```

With javascript:

```
document.getElementById("sound_element").innerHTML= 
    "<embed src='"+sound_file_url+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
```

There're even easier ways with HTML5.

But please don't use it in sites I use, thanks.

Comment: Firefox doesn't support mp3 playback in HTML5 `audio` tags as far as I remember, so your `embed` is probably better for cross-browser compatibility and older IE versions.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté. It's supported since 3.5 [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio) I added all the options, choose what you like the most.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I remember testing it after Nightly 15a release and it returned a "mp3 format playback is not supported" (or similar) error in the console (while working perfectly fine on Chrome), that's a little off-topic so I'll post a question if I can't sort it out by myself.

Comment: [Why doesn't Firefox support mp3 file format in <audio>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4923195/1331430), [Is there any way that HTML Audio tag could play mp3 in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10675507/1331430), [MP3 in Audio Tag in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7492319/1331430). Nope, no `mp3` support in Firefox's `audio` tags. `:)`

Comment: Can I do this without creating a div?